# c++ tcp send() slow

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, send

I have the code like this:

```
std::string msg = "blablabla" // a large string, even like 100-200KB
int total = 0;
int left = msg.size();
int resp_len;

while (total < resp.size())
{
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    resp_len = send(*p_fd, msg.substr(total).c_str(), left, 0);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    cout << end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec << endl; // each send takes like 2-4 ms

    if (resp_len == -1)
        break;

    total += resp_len;
    left -= resp_len;
}
```

As you can see in that comment, each send() call takes like 2-4 milliseconds, which is a bit too much for my needs and I'm pretty sure it could be faster, but I don't really know how... The socket is in non-blocking mode, but other than that I haven't set anything. On the client side I get the message just fine, but when I'm measuring how long it takes to get the whole message it gets to like 8-18 ms. Usually the message comes with 3 send() calls, so it takes 6-12 ms already, the connecting time and the processing is like 0.

Any idea how could I make that send() call faster? I've seen other programs sending 100-200KB much faster...

Comment: Actually you're not measuring the time of `send` itself. You're also doing a dereference, calling `substr`, and `c_str()`. And - of course - calling `gettimeofday` once (you're getting `start.tv_usec` __after__ calling, so - yes - only once).

Comment: I've tried taking out the substr() part from the measuring, but the result was the same. Each send took the same time (well obviously there was a difference, but I wasn't able to see it really).

Comment: I tried running your program on my computer (2.7GHz mac mini, OS/X 10.9.3) and it took 127 microseconds (note: microseconds not milliseconds!) to complete the loop (sending 100kB of data).  I replaced 'msg.substr(total).c_str()' with 'msg.c_str()+total' and that reduced the time to 87 microseconds.  Note that I was sending to another program running on localhost though; if you're sending across the network the expected times will be larger.

Comment: Btw what program is receiving your data?  With TCP, a slow receiver will cause the sending program to slow down to match it; so the problem may be there rather than in your sending code.

Comment: Hm... changed it to msg.c_str()+total and it's much better now. Went down to around 30 microseconds. It's a bit weird, now it's super fast... Thanks! I'm testing on localhost btw, so network shouldn't have been a problem.

Comment: Cool -- substr() was constructing another (up to) 100kB string on each iteration of the loop, which is inefficient.

Comment: One more thing -- if the socket is really in non-blocking mode, then sending in a loop is going to spin your CPU if the receiver is slow.  (try it -- temporarily at a sleep(1) into your receiver's receive-loop and you'll see the above code's send() return -1/EWOULDBLOCK over and over again while the receiver sleeps).  You'd be better off either using non-blocking I/O here, or taking care to block inside select() until the socket is ready-for-ready, or refactoring to a state-machine-based approach.

Comment: I'm using epoll and handling these kind of errors, so this shouldn't be a problem, but thanks for mentioning!